# How can I disable swappiness just for Mariadb and not for other applications on the same EC2 Instance?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.5

I have an EC2 instance where DB(Mariadb) runs on the same EC2 instance as the other applications.
MySQL documentation suggests to disable swappiness since DB doesn't like swap. How can I disable swappiness just for Mariadb and not for all other users/apps ?
Thanks
Moe

Comment: Swappiness is a kernel parameter and as such affects everything that runs on the system. Typically you shouldn't have "other users/apps" on the database server, so this wouldn't be a problem if you wished to change the swappiness setting.

Comment: @mustaccio-Unfortunately all non prod environments are shared meaning db and apps run on the same server, not my design but that's something I inherited and can't change due to cost.

Answer (score 2):

Plan A (if possible):  Use "huge pages" for the buffer_pool.  They can't be swapped, thereby helping keep from swapping MariaDB.

Plan B:  Use swappiness = 1 -- This, in theory, discourages the OS from swapping any process.  It will still swap if it is absolutely necessary.  At that point, perhaps it is better to slow down some process(es) rather than crashing?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Plan B will prevent swapping for any process so it won't meet my requirement of disabling swap just for mariadb. I will try Plan A.

Comment: @Moe - Please report back on how well it worked.